# Can I switch active_group real time in CodeIgniter?

Tags: database, codeigniter

I want to use a different database that's defined in my $active_group in my database.php

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No... But you can actually Initialize the database class with defined parameter from your controller/model/library... example:

test = $this->load->database($config);
}

function index()
{
$this->test->get()... // bla bla bla.
}
}
?>

Hope this helps :)